# ionic select won't render properly with dynamic values? Ionic 4

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am facing a problem while using ionic 4, and ionic-select.
The problem comes when i have some data and i am binding the data.
In this example, i already have a pre selected data, when i do so the ion-select does not render properly.

```
      <ion-item class="transparent">
        <ion-label position='floating'>{{ 'GENDER_TXT' | translate}}</ion-label>
        <ion-select interface="popover" color='medium' [(ngModel)]='Gender' formControlName='genderTxt'>
          <ion-select-option *ngFor='let g of Genders' [value]='g'>{{g.GENDER}}</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
```

```
      this.getGendersSub = this.proxy.Get_Genders(param).subscribe((data) => {
        this.Genders = data;
        this.Gender = this.Genders[0];
      });
```

[Demo Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys3Ix.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the ngmodel directive`[(ngModel)]='Gender'` when you use reactive form , you can set the selected value by update form control `genderTxt` value

```js
this.getGendersSub = this.proxy.Get_Genders(param).subscribe((data) => {
  this.Genders = data;
  this.form.get(`genderTxt`).setValue(this.Genders[0]);
 });
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-9gkd1i)

Comment: if you are using formControl you will need to patchValue method to selected value

Comment: @MhmdKorhani I have update my answer with working demo 

Comment: @malbarmawi thanks for updating your answer, this is an ionic 3 demo which is working fine for me, the problem is with ionic 4 and ionic-angular modules, my problem was fixed using the following methodology: hiding the select element until my dynamic data is received.